# Using SkiaSharp.SKBitmap image as the ImageSource for a Button in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am attempting to use/convert the `SKBitmap` image as/to an `ImageSource` object in order to use the aforementioned image in a `Button` by assignment to its `ImageSource` property but, for the life of me, cannot figure out how to convert an `SKBitmap` object to an `ImageSource`.

Searching the web only yielded the articles/issues on converting an `ImageSource` to `SKBitmap` but not the converse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't do this directly.  You could use AsPNG/AsJPEG to write it to a file and use FileImageSource, or convert to SKPixMap and Encode as a PNG/JPG and then use a stream to create an image source

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ImageSource` property of the `Button` class is of `ImageSource` type, whose value can be set to that of a string representing the path of an image either via assigning the string to the property or using the `ImageSource.FromFile()` method. As the `ImageSource` type cannot be used with `SKBitmap` images, the image represented by the `SKBitmap` object can be saved to the disk (preferably in the application cache) and the path to the saved image can be used to initialize the concerned `ImageSource` object.

```
SKBitmap bitmap;

SKImage image = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap);
SKData encodedData = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
string imagePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "image.png");
bitmapImageStream = File.Open(imagePath, 
                              FileMode.Create, 
                              FileAccess.Write, 
                              FileShare.None);
encodedData.SaveTo(bitmapImageStream);
bitmapImageStream.Flush(true);
bitmapImageStream.Dispose();

ImageSource imgSrc;
imgSrc = ImageSource.FromFile(imagePath);
// or imgSrc = imagePath;
```

Answer (score 13):

You could try this:

```
SKBitmap bitmap = ...;
// create an image COPY
//SKImage image = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap);
// OR
// create an image WRAPPER
SKImage image = SKImage.FromPixels(bitmap.PeekPixels());
// encode the image (defaults to PNG)
SKData encoded = image.Encode();
// get a stream over the encoded data
Stream stream = encoded.AsStream();
img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(()=> stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the NuGet SkiaSharp.Views.WPF like:

```
...
using BarcodeStandard;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.WPF;
...
SKImage image = new Barcode().Encode(Type.Code128A, text, width, height);
...
ImageSource imageSource = WPFExtensions.ToWriteableBitmap(image);
...
```