# What is the fastest way to display large datasets as images in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform, maui

I am building a cross-platform application using .NET MAUI that needs to display large sets of data.
The data comes in as a 2D float[,] array, each point gets attributed a Color and should then be displayed on the screen. Here is what I am after:
[Example of how the data should be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07sdG.png)

Because the data set can be extremely large (2000 rows x 1000000 columns for example), if I try to simply load it entirely as an Image or GraphicView, it takes a very long time.

So what I want to do is draw the data one column at the time. How can I achieve this?

My most successful attempt so far has been to use an IDispatcherTimer timer in the C# code behind the view:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    string pathToTheDataset = Path.Combine(appFolderPath, "large_dataset");

    IDispatcherTimer timer;
    timer = Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

    int columnNumber = 0;
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        AppendImage(pathToTheDataset, columnNumber, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        Color[] column = ExtractOneColumn(pathToTheDataset, columnNumber);

        SkiaBitmapExportContext bitmap = new SkiaBitmapExportContext(width, height, 1.0f);
        ICanvas canvas = bitmap.Canvas;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < column.Length; i++)
        {
            canvas.StrokeColor = column[i]
            canvas.DrawRectangle(columnNumber, i, 1, 1)
        }

        var skImage = bitmap.SKImage;
        SKData encodedData = skImage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100)

        string imagePath = Path.Combine(AppFolder, "data.png");

        var bitmapImageStream = File.Open(imagePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

        encodedData.SaveTo(bitmapImageStream);
        bitmapImageStream.Flush(true);
        bitmapImageStream.Dispose();

        dataImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imagePath);

        columnNumber++;
        if (columnNumber == numberOfColumn - 1)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    };

    timer.Start();
}
```

This code was inspired by the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293110/using-skiasharp-skbitmap-image-as-the-imagesource-for-a-button-in-xamarin).

The timer allows me to update the ImageSource of the Image (x:Name = "dataImage") in my View but I do not understand how to add the next column to the previous one in that Image.

I have tried to break this code into several methods so that it only updates the SkiaBitmapExportContext object but then the Image remains stuck at the first column although the timer increments as it should with no error/exception.

Any suggestion is welcomed, thank you.

Comment: Try to create the image as a file and show it to the user with a webview. Maybe this will be faster.

Comment: decide what size you want your image to be and set pixel colors according to average values of corresponding blocks of data. theres no sense in creating of such a huge image, if you don't have a gigapixel monitor

Comment: What do you mean by "2D Dataset"? Do you have image data (i.e. a 2D raser)? or 2D Point data? For image data, it is mostly a question of transforming your floats to a rgb or byte value, and possibly either clip or downscale the data to fit the screen.

Comment: @MikeTsayper, the image control is inside a ScrollView so any screen will be fine really. It is important for us that the users have access to the full image so that they can scroll and zoom to analyze parts of the data that they find interesting.

Comment: @JonasH , I meant a 2D float[,] array. I have attempted to transform the data in a byte[] array containing the rgb values of each point before. It works if you target only Android or only Windows (without .NET MAUI), but I haven't found a way to do it cross-platform yet.

Comment: @Patapon create zoomed portions of image upon the user's request. Computers cant handle gigapixel images with sufficient speed yet

Comment: The reason for the slow response is you are refreshing the view after adding each row.  To speed up the process is to fill the view and then do one update after all the data is put into the view.

Comment: @jdweng, but if I do that, then filling up the canvas in one go is what takes a long time.

Comment: @MikeTsayper, I don't think "gigapixels" are needed, we have a released version of this app on Android, and it is working fine. I have loaded a big dataset on MAUI as well (without the timer, just loading it all at once) and although the loading was super slow, once down it was working fine inside its ScrollView.

Comment: No.  It is the refreshing of the canvas after each row that is taking the time.

Comment: Create a GraphicsView with an IDrawable. The cool thing is regardless of the size of your source data, your target, i.e. your screen has a finite number of pixels. So, you can always render in an optimal manner retrieving only the data that is needed. Start with a crude nearest-neighbour interpolation algorithm.

Comment: @StephenQuan that was my first try, it works very nicely for small canvas but becomes sluggish for big ones. One more problem is that the draw method will be called each time the UI needs updating (screen resize, popup showing, ...). Is there a way to make it async somehow? But even async will be slow to show if the canvas contains many elements.

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt the PlatformImage Learn .NET sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images which seems to demonstrate (1) FromStream, (2) Downsize, (3) canvas.DrawImage()

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). This may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem which worked on both Windows and Android (I did not test iOS and mac). I tested it on a dataset that had 512 rows x 55856 columns and I could draw the image in < 2 seconds (from reading the file containing the dataset all the way to showing the Image on screen).

Admittedly the dataset is smaller than what I specified in my question but it is the biggest dataset I have at my disposal right now. Also < 2 seconds is the time it took to dump everything at once in the Image and it is possible to improve user experience by progressively updating the image instead.

Here is the code:

1. Write pixel in a byte array.

```
private async Task WritePixelsAsync()
{
    pixelArray = new byte[numberOfColumns * numberOfRows * 4]; 
   // The 4 is because ARGB is 32 bits per pixel and 1 byte = 8 bits.

    int loopIndex = 0;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns * 4; i += 4)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfRows; j++)
            {
                // Create a color scale, in my case I want a grey scale.
                int greyScale = (int)MathF.Round(data[loopIndex, j] / 256 + 128);
                greyScale = Math.Clamp(greyScale, 0, 255);

                //BGRA order because it is a bitmap.
                pixelArray[i + (numberOfColumns * 4 * j)] = (byte)greyScale;
                pixelArray[i + 1 + (numberOfColumns  * 4 * j)] = (byte)greyScale;
                pixelArray[i + 2 + (numberOfColumns * 4 * j)] = (byte)greyScale;
                pixelArray[i + 3 + (numberOfColumns * 4 * j)] = 255;
            }
            loopIndex++;
        }
    });
}
```

2. Create a bitmap manually and put it in a MemoryStream.

```
private static MemoryStream GenerateBitmapStreamFromPixelArray(int numberOfColumns, int numberOfRows, byte[] pixelArray)
{
    int bitsPerPixel = 32; // 32 bits per pixel (ARGB)
    int rowSize = numberOfColumns * (bitsPerPixel / 8);
    int imageSize = rowSize * numberOfRows;

    byte[] headerBytes = new byte[54]; // Header size is 54 bytes for bitmap format.
    
    // Bitmap file header (14 bytes)
    headerBytes[0] = 0x42; // Signature ('B')
    headerBytes[1] = 0x4D; // Signature ('M')
    BitConverter.GetBytes(14 + 40 + imageSize).CopyTo(headerBytes, 2); // File size
    BitConverter.GetBytes(54).CopyTo(headerBytes, 10); // Offset to image data

    // Bitmap info header (40 bytes)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(40).CopyTo(headerBytes, 14); // Info header size
    BitConverter.GetBytes(numberOfColumns).CopyTo(headerBytes, 18); // Image width
    BitConverter.GetBytes(numberOfRows).CopyTo(headerBytes, 22); // Image height
    headerBytes[26] = 1; // Number of color planes
    headerBytes[28] = (byte)bitsPerPixel; // Bits per pixel
    BitConverter.GetBytes(imageSize).CopyTo(headerBytes, 34); // Image size
    BitConverter.GetBytes(resolution).CopyTo(headerBytes, 38); // Horizontal resolution (pixels per meter)
    BitConverter.GetBytes(resolution).CopyTo(headerBytes, 42); // Vertical resolution (pixels per meter)

    // Reverse the order of rows in pixelArray because bitmap format wants data as "little endian" and not "big endian".
    byte[] reversedPixelArray = new byte[pixelArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        int sourceIndex = (numberOfRows - 1 - i) * rowSize;
        int targetIndex = i * rowSize;
        Array.Copy(pixelArray, sourceIndex, reversedPixelArray, targetIndex, rowSize);
    }

    // Append reversed pixel data to the header
    byte[] bmpData = new byte[headerBytes.Length + reversedPixelData.Length];
    headerBytes.CopyTo(bmpData, 0);
    reversedPixelData.CopyTo(bmpData, headerBytes.Length);

    MemoryStream stream = new(bmpData);
    return stream;
}
```

I used this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) to learn how to properly write the bitmap format.

3. Update your Image's ImageSource from the MemoryStream.

```
ImageSource.FromStream(() => GenerateBitmapStreamFromPixelArray(numberOfColumns, numberOfRows, pixelArray));
```

Note that there is another solution that I found using a combination of SKBitmap, SkiaImage and MemoryStream; it is a bit slower but requires much less code, if your datasets are not as large as mines maybe it is worth investigating.